# disable android keyboard quick fixes

Tags: android

The Android keyboard changes the text entered by the user, for example if the user enters 2 spaces, they are replaced by '. ' (a period and a space).  How can i disable this quick fix feature in code?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set autoText to false in the xml properties of that TextView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoText

Comment: that works, unless the user has quick fix enabled in their keyboard settings.  I was hoping that I could override the keyboard settings.